# Chef IIS Cookbook thirty_two_bit option not working

Tags: iis, chef-infra, cookbook

I have a resource block to create an app pool, make thirty_two_bit option as true and assign an username and password.

```
iis_pool 'CPool' do
runtime_version "2.0"
pipeline_mode :"Classic"
recycle_after_time "0"
thirty_two_bit true
pool_username "testuser"
pool_password "testpd"
action :add
```

It creates an app pool but the following options didn't work.

```
recycle_after_time "0"
thirty_two_bit true
pool_username "testuser"
pool_password "testpd"
```

I am wondering if it is a bug. Any notes on this is appreciated - Eben

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing two different actions together. Viewing the [Chef source here](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/iis/blob/master/providers/pool.rb) I can tell that you want to call both `:add` to create the pool and then `:config` to do the rest. So break it up as:

```
iis_pool 'CPool' do
   runtime_version "2.0"
   pipeline_mode :"Classic"
action :add

iis_pool 'CPool' do
   recycle_after_time "0"
   thirty_two_bit true
   pool_username "testuser"
   pool_password "testpd"
action :config
```

Comment: in v3.0.0 (alpha) of iis opscode cookbook this is no longer needed, the :add command will set it up initially correctly.